# Insert HTML special characters in (i18n) yml

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to insert a special character in the html file translation.
The character is a space, need it to try to solve another problem.

But it is not working. The code for that character is displayed in the subject of the email.

For this I insert these lines:

pt.yml

```
subjects:
  ...
  release_auto_pause_triggered_html: "%{project_name} %{release_name} - pausa automática &nbsp; disparada"
```

release_mailer.rb

```
subject = t('subjects.release_auto_pause_triggered_html', project_name: @project.name, release_name: @release.name).html_safe
```

But the subject of the email sent is as follows: `pausa automática&nbsp;disparada`

- The "'" I added just to make this post, but it would not give to see here.

I need to look like this: "pausa automática disparada"

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Rails doesn't decode HTML entities. Just add another translation entry without `&nbsp` or replace it with an actual [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), i.e. `\u00A0`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I manage to do it. Try this `"pausa automática\xA0disparada"`

[Source](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation):

> Using single-quoted scalars, you may express any value that does not contain special characters. No escaping occurs for single quoted scalars except that a pair of adjacent quotes '' is replaced with a lone single quote '.
>
> Double-quoted is the most powerful style and the only style that can express any scalar value. Double-quoted scalars allow escaping. Using escaping sequences \x** and \u****, you may express any ASCII or Unicode character.

And [here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) I found the necessary code

My output is:

```
# YML
title: "Title \xA0 aaa"
# console
I18n.t('title')
=> "Title   aaa"
```

Comment: *-* It worked, thanks for the code, for the explanation and the source. =]

Answer (score 1):

It should work this way. Try to check for typos.

In your example

> "pausa automática&nbsp';disparada""

there is extra `'` between `&nbsp` and `;`.

Comment: No in my code. Just here. I had to insert a 'here to show the code.